# C/C++ Console Windows WIN32

Tags: c++

I know how to "hide" them. I know about FreeConsole(); and then finding the handle and changing it's attributes. However with these methods the window still pops up for a second than goes away. How can I stop it from showing up completely?

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered creating a windows application (with [windows subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk(vs.71,loband).aspx)) instead of a console application? That should hide the console window all together.

Try looking at [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85,loband).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to be a GUI application to not have the console displayed.  Check out [/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx)